# Docker change apache2.conf from dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've been wrestling with this Dockerfile for a while:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN echo "Etc/UTC" > /etc/timezone

# export timezone - for python3.9-dev install
ENV TZ=Europe/London

# place timezone data /etc/timezone
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

# Install Apache and PHP
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y apache2 php libapache2-mod-php apache2-dev

# Enable mod_rewrite
RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nano

RUN sed -i 's/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN echo "LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80

# Start Apache in foreground mode
CMD ["apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

The docker compose up works and completes, and the server comes up. BUT, two things don't work:

These lines appear so never be executed??

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nano

RUN sed -i 's/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN echo "LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

When I cli into the docker instance, nano isn't available until I install it, ironically using the same command: `apt-get install -y nano`

And when I edit the apache2.conf file, none of the AllowOverride values are changed to All AND the LoadModule line isn't in the file...

Why would these lines be skipped / not running / and really, how do I accomplish this??

(additional: when I run each line on the terminal on the container, there are no errors and it works as expected. I've also tried `docker build --no-cache -t myimage .` with no change in the files)

Comment: I tested your Dockerfile, it works fine.

Comment: when you look at the apache2.conf file on the instance, does it have the mods from those three lines?? Mine runs, but those mods are never executed.

Comment: Yes I checked all parts must be changed in apache.conf and all of them was there.